# How to keep Java HashMap in final class from being removed when Android application is closed and rerun?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a `final static ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>` in my application, I am able to add to it and remove from it just fine. My problem is when my Android application closes the `ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>` is empty when I re-run the application.

Can someone please help explain to me how to persist this type of Map across applications runs?

Example Code: This class is referenced from my a simple Main Activity with a list view

```
 public final class HashMapDemo{

     public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> mapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();

     public static addToMap(String key, String value){

          mapping.put(key, value);


      }

    public static removeFromMap(String key){

         mapping.remove(key);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is closed (i.e., removed from memory), then there is no way to have an object which only exists in memory to remain alive.

The only way around this is to persist your data in some storage methods such as SharedPreferences, SQLite, the file system, etc - then make sure to save your hash map's data when the app's about to close, and restore it when the app becomes alive.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Looks like SQLite or file storage is what I will do. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is when my Android application closes the ConcurrentHashMap is empty when i re run the application.

Static data members will go away when your process terminates. This is no different than with most other programming languages and operating systems.

> Can someone please help explain to me how to persist this type of Map across applications runs?

Store the data in a persistent location, such as a file.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will have to store values to shared preferences or SQLite.